# Possible strings of length N with 3 characters

Tags: string, algorithm, math, combinations, permutation

I have 3 characters - 'a', 'b', 'c'. I need to make strings of length N where N >= 3. **Each of the characters has to be present in the strings at least once.** Repetition of characters is allowed. So how many such strings are possible.

Comment: Are you trying to generate *one* such string? Are you trying to generate *all* of the strings? Are you simply trying to *count* how many strings are possible? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to know how many strings are possible?

Comment: Infinite. As per your requirements...

Comment: What? Give valid answer

Comment: @DavidEisenstat can you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

First:
For `N=3`, you have to form your string with the characters `"abc"` (1 initial string)

For `N=4`, you have to form your string with either: `"abca"`, `"abcb"` or `"abcc"` (3 initial strings)

For `N=5`, take each string from `N=4` and append `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` to form three strings from one. (9 in total)

So, for a given `N`, the number of possible "initial" strings you can use is `3^(N-3)`

But:
for every initial string of length N, the number of possible different strings is N!

For example, for N=3, the initial string is "abc", but this string can be permuted to form 6 different strings:

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

So, the total number of possible strings of length `N` in which the characters `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` appears at least once is: `(3^(N-3))*N!`

```
For N=3, it's 6
    N=4,      72
    N=5,      1080
    N=6,      19440
    N=7,      408240
    N=8,      9797760
    N=9,      264539520
    N=10,     7936185600
    ...
    N=32,     1.8058768635096880150713941583736e+49
```

Comment: This assumes that `abca` is different from `abca`, doesn't it? (The second string has the first and last elements swapped.)

Comment: For N = 4, the answer should be 36. So I think the solution considers duplicates.

Comment: You are right! I am not considering possible duplicates. Sorry! :(